# Batik's SVGDocument.getElementsByTagNameNS returns empty NodeList despite of namespace and tagname being correctly set

Tags: java, xml, svg, batik

I have a part of code parsing SVG document.

```
String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
        SAXSVGDocumentFactory factory = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
        SVGDocument svgDocument = null;
        try {
            //svgDocument = factory.createSVGDocument(IMAGE_SVG);
            svgDocument = factory.createSVGDocument("file://", new FileInputStream(f
            ));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        NodeList gs= svgDocument.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","g");
        NodeList pathes = svgDocument.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
```

For strange reason `gs` and `pathes` bear no nodes inside. While in debugger is see that svgDocument identified `elementsById` inside it correctly, while `elementsByTagNames` and `elementsByTagNamesNS` are empty. How to resolve that issue? How to make elements load by tag name too?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some issue with file loading

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    docBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    String line = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path to file")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(line)));
```

and that document returns `.getElementsByTagNameNS` as wanted